# How to fix menu in IE compatibility / quirks mode

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser, quirks-mode

I have a [Wordpress website](http://www.myhomecare.ie) built using the Sterling theme and I'm having issues with the menu displaying vertically instead of horizontally in Internet Explorer. I asked about it before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003211/errors-loading-wordpress-website-on-internet-explorer-8) and ended up focusing on jquery errors that didn't fix the problem.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgi57.jpg) of how its showing up on IE9 for me.

Since then I tried changing the doctype to force the site to display properly but I've now realized that all the computers at work have IE9 permanently set to compatibility mode and changing that would mean going through the IT department.

I can't exactly tell my company the website looks wrong on your computers but right everywhere else and I do want to avoid errors for people using old versions of IE since the target market isn't tech savvy people, so could anyone offer advice on how I can get my menu to work right in quirks / compatibility mode?

I don't care if other aspects of the site aren't perfect but its practically unusable with the menu like that. I basically just need it to display horizontally instead of vertically, which I'm assuming is related to the CSS somehow.

EDIT: Added my CSS

The original code in the stylesheet is this

```
nav > ul > li {
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
}

nav > ul > li+li {
margin-left:28px;
}
```

And then I customised it slightly in the site options part of the theme (basically means my changes won't get overwritten when I update the theme) and my customization is:

```
nav > ul > li+li {
font-size:14px;
margin-left:10px 
}
```

I think its something to do with display:inline-block; but nothing I've tried seems to make the menu horizontal again.

Comment: position: relative; is not needed.

and when you try to make a difference for only one element (like for your margin ie) you should use selectors. (:first-child or :last-child)

Answer (score 0):

What css properties have you used for that ? You should do something like

```
#menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
}

#menu {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I gave that a try and messed around a bit with a few similar fixes I've found online but no luck yet. I've edited the original to show my css.